# Reading a bitmap image from a file

Tags: java, image, bmp

I used the following code to write an image to a file using `BI_RLE8` compression.  How can I read back the image saved in that file?

```
BufferedImage source = new BufferedImage(200, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

ImageWriter writer  = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("bmp").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("BI_RLE8");

writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(new File("c:\\RLE.bmp")));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(source, null, null), param);
writer.dispose();
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes, by the brevious code i encoded an image "source" and stored the result in RLE.dat file    how can i get it back as an image

Comment: It is stored in `c:\\RLE.bmp`  How you can access it depemds on what you want to do with it.

Comment: i wanna view it as an image agian and calculate RMSE between it and the original image

Comment: where? windows - use windows explorer.  On the web ? Swing?

Comment: using netbeans to manipulate it

Comment: netbeans is a Java IDE isnt it?  File-Open?

Comment: yes, but the file is encoded >> BI_RLE8 is a run length encoding algorithm... now i wanna decode it first, then viwe it as an image again .. but how to decode. shall i use ImageReader, 
ImageWriter is from the API "javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;"

Comment: Clarified question and tags from comments